# Why do I get an (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) error with the sequential model in keras on gpu and what can I do about it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, gpu, theano

I want to see if I can make changes to my code so that I can train a keras sequential model. When I run my python script then it fails on the following line:

```
data = model.fit(LSTM_training_inputs[:-pred_range], LSTM_training_outputs, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=1,verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

The model is created using the following code:

```
def build_model(inputs, output_size, neurons, activ_func="linear",dropout=0.25, loss="mae", optimizer="adam"):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(units=output_size))
    model.add(Activation(activ_func))

    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)
    return model
```

My Python console produces the following output (the tail of the output 
 anyways):

```
Epoch 1/100

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

It is worth mentioning that I am using a theano backend for keras and my .theanorc file contains the following.

```
[blas]
ldflags =

[global] 
floatX = float32
device = opencl0:1

# By default the compiled files were being written to my local network drive.
# Since I have limited space on this drive (on a school's network),
# we can change the path to compile the files on the local machine.
# You will have to create the directories and modify according to where you 
# want to install the files. 
# Uncomment if you want to change the default path to your own.
# base_compiledir = /local-scratch/jer/theano/

[nvcc]
fastmath = True

[gcc]
cxxflags = -ID:\MinGW\include

[cuda]
# Set to where the cuda drivers are installed.
# You might have to change this depending where your cuda driver/what version is installed.
```

Is there any way to make it so that the program doesn't crash with a SIGABRT error when fitting the model?

Comment: Does it works with CPU? Have you verified your dimensions are correct when defining your model? How large a data-set are you training on and what does your memory-usage look like while training?

Comment: It works with cpu. The dataset is a few hundred thousand times one hundred in size. I presume dimensions would be correct since it works with cpu. Thanks for the help!